# What is the difference between distributed cloud computing and fog computing?

Tags: cloud

According to Wiki page definition, Distributed cloud computing is "Cloud computing can also be provided by a distributed set of machines that are running at different locations, while still connected to a single network or hub service."

How is this different from fog computing?

Fog computing as defined by wiki "Fog computing or fog networking is an architecture that uses one or a collaborative multitude of end-user clients or near-user edge devices to carry out a substantial amount of storage (rather than stored primarily in cloud data centers), communication (rather than routed over the internet backbone), and control, configuration, measurement and management (rather than controlled primarily by network gateways such as those in the LTE (telecommunication) core)."

Comment: What's the definition of "fog computing"?

Comment: Those two definitions are vastly different.

Comment: Difference is only in terms of where they are implemented, an end device(edge) or a machine I think. Is there any other difference?

Comment: do you have any reference to fog computing and where can I read about this technology?

Answer (score 1):

Fog computing uses heterogeneous devices and is focused on providing computing power and storage at the "edge of the internet" as opposed to Distributed cloud computing which still acts as a single, contiguous "system".

Answer (score 0):

Distributed cloud may be composed of several large data centers which are distributed geographically. While the idea of fog computing is to use the edge or near-edge devices which lead to small data centers close to end user.